# In XMonad, how can I always give a certain window a specific floating position?

Tags: xmonad, window-position

The title is pretty self-explanatory I think.

In XMonad, how can I always give a certain window a specific floating position?

```
james@computron ~ $ xwininfo 

xwininfo: Please select the window about which you
          would like information by clicking the
          mouse in that window.

xwininfo: Window id: 0x32dcf3b "Tabs Outliner"

  Absolute upper-left X:  1280
  Absolute upper-left Y:  25
  Relative upper-left X:  1280
  Relative upper-left Y:  25
  Width: 1278
  Height: 997
  Depth: 24
  Visual: 0x21
  Visual Class: TrueColor
  Border width: 1
  Class: InputOutput
  Colormap: 0x20 (installed)
  Bit Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Window Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Backing Store State: NotUseful
  Save Under State: no
  Map State: IsViewable
  Override Redirect State: no
  Corners:  +1280+25  -0+25  -0-0  +1280-0
  -geometry 1278x997-0-0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a *tiled*, rather than floating, fixed window is acceptable check out [XMonad.Layout.IM](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Layout-IM.html), which allows you to tie one window to the left-hand side of a workspace.  If you prefer the right-hand side, you can reflect the layout with [XMonad.Layout.Reflect](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Layout-Reflect.html)

Comment: Tiled is even better.  This looks like it will do exactly what I want, so I'm accepting even though I haven't had time to try it yet.